# Will a stereo amplifier with a power supply range of 12V to 25V DC run off a 12V car battery?

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, dc, 12v

If an amplifier has a power supply input range of 12V to 25V will it actually run off a 12V DC battery system such as a 12V solar system? Here is a link to an example amplifier:
https://fosiaudio.com/collections/old-version-sale/products/bt10a-bluetooth-4-0-stereo-audio-amplifier-receiver-2-channel-class-d-mini-hi-fi-integrated-amp-for-home-speakers-50w-x-2-tpa3116

Comment: It seems like it will work. But not really enough information to say for sure whether it can deliver full power. Make sure the solar panel Voc is less than 25V (should be no problem for so-called 12V panels). If you don't have a battery, it may behave strangely in low light conditions.

Comment: Car battery really has between 12.6- 14.4 Volts. So it is in range of demands for amplifier.

Comment: @user263983 That's not correct. [A car battery that's being discharged will be below 12.6V](https://www.energymatters.com.au/components/battery-voltage-discharge/). But still above 12.0V as long as it's not discharged too much (or has to supply large currents).

Comment: @starcat where is no sense to run audio amplifier from discharged battery. Audio amplifier consume a lot of power.

Comment: @user263983 did I write a “discharged” battery? I wrote about a battery being in the process of discharging. I.e. a battery that’s being used and not charged at that moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description mentions TPA3116D2 which is a D-class power amplifier that can work from 4.5V up to 26V, so a 12V car battery (that actually walks between 10V and 15V depending on its state of charge and the presence of a charger) lies well within this range.

The rated power (50W at 4 ohm) is achieved at 21V power input voltage. The less voltage, the less maximal power. The datasheet tells something like 25W at 14.4V (the voltage in a car with engine running).

!!! pure speculation below !!!

The rest of the device is the bluetooth circuit which itself runs at either 5.0V, 3.3V or 1.8V, derived internally from whatever power supply is available.

!!! ---------------------- !!!

I think you can safely run it off a 12V car battery if you are OK with somewhat reduced maximum output power. There is a nice graph in the TPA3116D2 datasheet.

Comment: I plan to run it off batteries from a solar system. I think the typical operating voltage is around 13V. I would likely use it with 8Ohm speakers. If I am reading the graphs right, it seems the power output at 13V with 8Ohm resistance is only 10W. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. If you want more power, your options are 4 Ohm speakers and/or using a boost converter to get 20..25V to power the amplifier.

Comment: It seems like a boost converter is a good option. It looks like a 12v to 24V 5A converter is about $15. I am curious how the amp I linked to compares to a typical auto amp/receiver with regards to sound quality and performance

Comment: 5A will not be enough. If you want to use the whole 2x50W you'll need something like 20A at 24V. Regarding the sound quality - the TPA3116D2 chip is designed for and likely used in a lot of car audio. Probably acceptable if you are not a hardcore audiophile.